# How to access viewport display color from within Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, color, instances

I'd like to use the viewport display color of an object to influence the Geometry Nodes of that object. This is possible within Shader Nodes through the use of the "Object Info" node, which is very helpful when instancing, [as shown here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUKqTiR6geA&)

It seems like a simple enough thing but my searches haven't gotten me anywhere. Any suggestions?